# Npm dependency error - node-sass not installing ,throwing error

Tags: npm, package.json, node-sass

Im using node version 16.2.0 and npm version 7.13, when i tried to run >npm install on the project, the following coming up,

```
npm ERR!code 1
npm ERR!path / Users / a.aashiq / Desktop / Projects / sdqui / node_modules / node - sass
npm ERR!command failed
npm ERR!command sh - c node - gyp rebuild ^
  npm ERR!1 error generated.
npm ERR!make: ** * [Release / obj.target / binding / src / binding.o] Error 1
npm ERR!gyp ERR!build error
npm ERR!gyp ERR!stack Error: `make`
failed with exit code: 2
npm ERR!gyp ERR!stack at ChildProcess.onExit(/Users/a.aashiq / Desktop / Projects / sdqui / node_modules / node - gyp / lib / build.js: 262: 23)
npm ERR!gyp ERR!stack at ChildProcess.emit(node: events: 365: 28)
npm ERR!gyp ERR!stack at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit(node: internal / child_process: 290: 12)
npm ERR!gyp ERR!System Darwin 20.4 .0
npm ERR!gyp ERR!command "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/node/16.2.0/bin/node"
"/Users/a.aashiq/Desktop/Projects/sdqui/node_modules/.bin/node-gyp"
"rebuild"
npm ERR!gyp ERR!cwd / Users / a.aashiq / Desktop / Projects / sdqui / node_modules / node - sass
npm ERR!gyp ERR!node - v v16 .2 .0
npm ERR!gyp ERR!node - gyp - v v3 .8 .0
npm ERR!gyp ERR!not ok

npm ERR!A complete log of this run can be found in:
  npm ERR!/Users/a.aashiq / .npm / _logs / 2021 - 05 - 25 T02_21_26_977Z - debug.log
```

I think there is some dependency clash between node-sass package and node or npm.And im using the node-sass package version `"node-sass": "^4.14.1",` in package.json file.It was running before well , i updated my mac , from then it was showing this error.I installed node via brew.It will be great help if it resolved.Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

Since im using CRA and node version of latest 16.x (my bad i installed from brew),some deps clash happened, so i uninstalled node from brew and managed to install LTS node v and rebuilt sass loader,it worked.Thanks